# JSON object restructure using ES6

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have something like this:

```js
tires: [{
  name: "fancyProduct1",
  quantity: 1
}, {
  name: "fancyProduct1",
  quantity: 1
}, {
  name: "fancyProduct1",
  quantity: 1
}, {
  name: "fancyProduct2",
  quantity: 1
}];
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is

```
tires: [{
  name: "fancyProduct1",
  quantity: 3
}, {
  name: "fancyProduct2",
  quantity: 1
}]
```

Any ideas on best way to approach this?

Comment: The main idea is to group products by name and sum their quantities. "have a quantity of 1" thanks that was a typo

Comment: Please help me understand your question. Are you trying to aggregate data? If it is for reporting purposes, there are several reporting tool which can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to restructure existing array of objects into the new ones

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, it is fixed now.

Comment: @BobanStanojevic Have you checked my [**soluton**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50983424/3669624) below?

Comment: Yes, @chŝdk Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce` to group the array into one object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
let tires = [{"name":"fancyProduct1","quantity":1},{"name":"fancyProduct1","quantity":1},{"name":"fancyProduct1","quantity":1},{"name":"fancyProduct2","quantity":1}];

let result = Object.values(tires.reduce((c, {name,quantity}) => {
  c[name] = c[name] || {name,quantity: 0}
  c[name].quantity += quantity;
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Reduce will accomplish this:

```
var products = { tires: [ {name: "fancyProduct1", quantity: 1}, {name: "fancyProduct1", quantity: 1}, {name: "fancyProduct1", quantity: 1}, {name: "fancyProduct2", quantity: 1}] };

var result = products.tires.reduce((acc,current) => {

    if (!acc[current.name]) {
       acc[current.name] = { name: current.name, quantity: 0};
    }

    acc[current.name].quantity++;

    return acc;
}, {});

var resultArray = Object.values(result);
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use a simple [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) call to loop over the `array` items, along with [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check for the existence of your iterated `item` in the `result` array and do your logic accordingly.

This is how should be your code:

```
var result = [];

tires.forEach(function(el) {
  let found = result.find(o => o.name === el.name);
  if (found) {
    found["quantity"] += el["quantity"];
  } else {
    result.push(el);
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var tires = [{
  name: "fancyProduct1",
  quantity: 1
}, {
  name: "fancyProduct1",
  quantity: 1
}, {
  name: "fancyProduct1",
  quantity: 1
}, {
  name: "fancyProduct2",
  quantity: 1
}];

var result = [];

tires.forEach(function(el) {
  let found = result.find(o => o.name === el.name);
  if (found) {
    found["quantity"] += el["quantity"];
  } else {
    result.push(el);
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can  do something like this...

```
var newTries = tires.map(n => (
 // logic for new array where you can get attributes of item in tires to create a new array. 
console.log(n);  // this can show what properties are available in the current item write it to the console. 
)};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please add the _logic for new array where you can get attributes of item in tires to create a new array._  to actually answer this